# Visual Studio C++ 2015: Multiple versions of same lib in one solution?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, lib

I try to keep an executable and a dll in one solution. Both depend on a library 'foo' which is included two times in the solution - one time for the executable and another for the dll. Furthermore the library code exists two times in different folders. 'foo' is under version control and it should be possible that the executable links to another version of 'foo' than the dll.

This also holds for the library 'bar' on which 'foo' depends.

Since the solution tags every project with a Guid and writes those back to the project files I end up with the following problem:

In one version of foo.vcxproj 'bar' is referenced by the Guid **abc** and in the other version of foo.vcxproj 'bar' is referenced with **xyz**.

Because foo.vcxproj is under version control, it clashes every time I update one of the local repositories.

Did anyone run into the same problem once and found a solution for this?

For clarifying here are some excerpts from the concerning files...

**mySolution.sln:** (a list of the included projects)

```
Project("{F184B08F-C81C-45F6-A57F-5ABD9991F28F}") = "App\foo", "foo.vcxproj", "{abc}"  
EndProject
Project("{F184B08F-C81C-45F6-A57F-5ABD9991F28F}") = "App\bar", "bar.vcxproj", "{def}"  
EndProject
Project("{F184B08F-C81C-45F6-A57F-5ABD9991F28F}") = "DLL\foo", "foo.vcxproj", "{uvw}"  
EndProject
Project("{F184B08F-C81C-45F6-A57F-5ABD9991F28F}") = "DLL\bar", "bar.vcxproj", "{xyz}"  
EndProject
```

**App\foo.vcxproj:**

```
<ProjectGuid>{abc}</ProjectGuid>
...
<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\bar\bar.vcxproj">
        <Project>{def}</Project>
     </ProjectReference>
</ItemGroup>
```

**DLL\foo.vcxproj:**

```
<ProjectGuid>{uvw}</ProjectGuid>
...
<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\bar\bar.vcxproj">
        <Project>{xyz}</Project>
     </ProjectReference>
</ItemGroup>
```

The problem is that the IDs given in the .sln file to the projects are also written to the .vcxproj files in two places:

1. in the ProjectGuid
2. in the ProjectReference section

So I end up with 2 versions of foo.vcxproj.

I can manage the ProjectGuid by setting a dummy id and ignoring the ProjectGuid lines by .git. But messing with the id in the ProjectReference section screws up the solution.

Comment: This should be possible. But what do you mean by *"the solution tags every project with a Guid"* and *"clashes every time"* ?  Can you share a minimal example?

Comment: It would also help if you list the error messages you get

Comment: Have you considered moving to a less integrated version control system?

Comment: @selbie I hope my Edit clarifies my problem :)

Comment: @Luis there are no errors. the problem is that I end up with 2 versions of a .vcxproj file where I should only have one.

Comment: @Yakk could you explain what you mean by a less integrated vcs. (I am using git.)

Comment: Ah, I now understand your question.  Your slns have guids that they want to share with guids in the vcxproj.  Maybe you can add a git munging step to strip out the guids on checkin?  And add the guids on checkout?  Or, perhaps more sanely, there are actually two `foo` in version control, and you merge changes regularly.  The two `foo`s have distinct guids as their one consistent difference.

Comment: @schmitze333 Thanks, that part is clearer. Now: (1) in my experience, solutions don't assign guids to projects, rather they reference each project's guids. (2) You said that "... it should be possible that the executable links to another version of 'foo' than the dll..." therefore it seems that in the end you should actually have two 'foo' projects in the solution (and your source code) and for what I know it's good they have different guids. (3) How does your directory tree look like, do both "..\bar\bar.vcxproj" paths point to the same location?

Comment: @Yakk Yes, I did this for the ProjectGuid part of the .vcxproj files and this works fine. Unfortunately this won't work for the references. Putting every foo into its own repository is not an option. I described a toy example... Our real production code consists of multiple executables each of them dealing with up to 40 dlls - all of depending on its own version of foo/bar...

Comment: @Luis (3) -> every "..\bar\bar.vcxproj" and "..\foo\foo.vcxproj" points to its own distinct location. (2) -> yes, I have 2 'foo' projects in the same solution and the source code. Maybe a different version of the latter... imagine one version of foo pointing to the latest release branch and the other to the current master branch. I don't see why the guids should play any role... a project should know how to build itself (here foo only needs to know that it should link against the bar that lies in the sibling directory) regardless into which solution it is importet.

Comment: @Luis (1) -> hmm, are you sure? Imagine 2 solutions.. each including the same project foo. But in solution 1 foo is listed with the id abc and in solution 2 foo is listed with the id xyz. If you build solution 1 and examine the foo.vcxproj file you find ProjectGuid abc. If you then build solution 2 and examine the same .vcxproj file the ProjectGuid has changed to xyz.

Comment: Btw. thank you guys for discussing with me in such detail!